# Logical Operators AND, OR, and a variable U

Tags: logical-operators

I encountered a set of `AND`, `OR` questions while I am applying for a Software Developer position, but I was confused by this set of boolean question that was provided:

```
(f or u) and not (t or f)
```

What does `u` mean and what is the return value of this boolean expression?

Comment: Unknown perhaps?

Comment: Presumably it is "unknown". "False or unknown" is "unknown". "True or unknown" is "true".

Comment: I'd urge against downvoting this. It's a very *basic* question, but it's clearly specified and is related to programming (or at least symbolic logic; it may belong in math.sx). It also doesn't appear to have an obvious duplicate on the site. Remember: simple/super-obvious/beginner questions aren't bad just because "everybody knows" the answer; if they're asked, and asked correctly, it means "everybody" doesn't!

Comment: [Wikipedia article: Three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

Comment: @OleV.V. That could be turned into an interesting answer

Answer (score 2):

Presumably "u" stands for "unknown".

```
(f or u) == u
(t or u) == t
(f and u) == f
(t and u) == u
```

For your question:

```
(f or u) and not (t or f)
```

is

```
(unknown and false)
```

which is

```
false
```

Put another way, `not (t or f)` is always `false`, so *and* ing it with anything will always give the result `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Does t and f stand for true and false? If it is, I guess you could get the value of your expression without knowing what u stands for.

```
=> (f or u) == u
=> (t or f) == t
=> not (t or f) == f
=> (f or u) and not (t or f) <=> u and f
=> Therefore, (u and f) == f
```

The whole expression will just be false regardless of the value of u.